# Test User has not the permission to use build in like?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, testing, facebook-opengraph, facebook-test-users

I am search like hours to find a solution to this problem. Maybe I am missing something?

I build a build-in Like Action in Open Graph for a native iOS App.
To get it through approval i also build a test website which will trigger this action from there.

Now the problem:
It works find for developers/administrator **but not for test-users**.

I get the following message:

`(#100) The Action Type likes:Like is not approved, so app xxxxxxx can only publish to administrators, developers, and testers of the app. User xxxxxxxxx is not one of those roles.`

I called the graph api with the Graph Api Explorer:

Method: Post

URL: https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes

Field: object = objectURL

Any ideas?